# Phonegap Geofencing plugin

Tags: android, cordova, cross-compiling, phonegap, geofencing

Someone else got any phonegap geofencing plugin working?? I can't even install the ones I've found and those are only cordova plugins, not really phonegap. 
I though it should work but it does not.

Edit1:Watchposition is not an option beacause it does not work on non https, so a webview in file:// protocol certainly will not help on that.

Edit2: I need something to work in background while the app is in  background, to stay running and get the coordinates of the geolocation.

Comment: geolocation work on file protocol, also you can install the geolocation plugin. Are you testing on the phonegap developer app?

Comment: Geolocation works fine to me. The problem is: I want some background process while the app is in background. I've searched many plugins but they just don't work for phonegap. Yes I am using phonegap CLI and works fine. I already have an app running but I need this feature, it's has been a pain to find something.

Comment: I'm asking, are you using Phonegap Developer App for testing your app? not the CLI, an app you install in your phone to preview your app without running it

Comment: No I am not, I am testing directy on device, via cli. I open the comand line and type the --device flag, so it runs on device. I stop using the phonegap app for test beacause many features crashed on it, so I changed for tests in the phone directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made `cordova-plugin-geofence` work on a Phonegap project:

Steps I made:

Install Phonegap CLI

```
npm install -g phonegap
```

create a Phonegap CLI project

```
phonegap create geofenceTest com.test.geofence geofenceTest
```

Added Android 7.0.0 platform with

```
phonegap platform add android@7.0.0
```

(you can also add 6.4.0, but the default one doesn't work if you have latest Android SDK tools)

Added the plugin with

```
phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-geofence
```

In config.xml change this line (it had 14, but 16 is needed for latest Cordova)

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
```

In index.js I added this in line 48

```
window.geofence.initialize(function(){alert('init ok');}, function(){alert('init error');});
```

Ran the app with:

```
phonegap run android --device
```

It asked for permissions and got the init ok alert

All the Cordova plugins are Phonegap plugins, Phonegap apps are Cordova apps

Comment: I will test it now, for now the install of geofence just worked, I can't undertand this because the same instalation does not work when I used the https link with add plaugin tag. I am adding everything to test following your instructions. Thanks in advice. When it runs I will comment again and rate the answer as solved. Thns again.

Comment: Thnks a lot! It works perfectly. The android platform already was seted and my min sdk version is 15 to support older android versions ( I think it's closer to 4.3.X or something like that ). Thnks again.